# How can I make my Ionic list look like this?

Tags: android, angular, user-interface, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and Angular and I'm trying to achieve a certain look for my Ionic list. I want to make my list items look like cards in a way. Here are two examples of what I mean:

[First Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZXvE.jpg)

[Second Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpxjV.png)

So far I tried to use ion-cards, but I couldn't make them look that way. I also tried getting a normal ion-list, but I have no idea how I would shape the items to look like wanted.

[Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEzj9.png)

```
 <ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
   <ion-avatar slot="start">
     <img src="assets/icon/favicon.png">
   </ion-avatar>
   <ion-label>
     <ion-grid>
       <ion-row>
         <ion-col size="12">
           <ion-label>{{item.text}}</ion-label>
         </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
       <ion-row>
         <ion-col size="2">
           <ion-label>+</ion-label>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col size="10">
           <ion-label>{{item.text2}}</ion-label>
         </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
     </ion-grid>
   </ion-label>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I used this so far as a reference
[Create Ionic card List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61854435/create-ionic-card-list)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried. This is not a free code provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to use the ionic-team's [2021 conference app source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/eas-2021) for your reverence. Its filled with useful examples of lists you can use in your app.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.